# Hexadecimal doubts and C + +

Tags: c++, pointers, hex

My question is: why is there a "--p", from what I understand the "++p"function serves to climb a number of imaginary array pointer, but the "--p" is for that? I realized that without it the code letters are not shown but did not understand how this works. thanks and even more

code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* p = new char [12];
    *p=0x48;
    ++p;
    *p=0x65;
    ++p;
    *p=0x6c;
    ++p;
    *p=0x6c;
    ++p;
    *p=0x6f;
    ++p;
    *p=0x20;
    ++p;
    *p=0x57;
    ++p;
    *p=0x6f;
    ++p;
    *p=0x72;
    ++p;
    *p=0x6c;
    ++p;
    *p=0x64;
    ++p;
    *p=0x0;
    ++p;

    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;
    --p;

    printf(p);
    delete p;

    return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: Was this entered as a IOCCC entrant? [And should it not be 13, and have a `*p=0x0a; p++;` before the `*p = 0x0; p++;` line?

Answer (score 1):

```
char *p = _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
         /\
```

Initially `p` points to the beginning of the array as shown

```
p++ == ++p == (p = p+1)
```

So this moves the pointer *forward* one place to the *right*.

```
p-- == --p == (p = p-1)
```

So this moves the pointer *back* one place to the *left*.

Answer (score 0):

Those are there to make `p` point to the beginning of the string that was just written.

There are several ways to improve all this, such as:

```
p -= 12;  // instead of all the --p
```

or

```
strcpy (p, "\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64");
```

or

```
p = new string ("\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64");
```

or even:

```
*p++ =0x48;
*p++ =0x65;
*p++ =0x6c;
*p++ =0x6c;
*p++ =0x6f;
*p++ =0x20;
*p++ =0x57;
*p++ =0x6f;
*p++ =0x72;
*p++ =0x6c;
*p++ =0x64;
*p    =0x0;

p -= 11;
```

or, to be direct *and* intuitive:

```
int main ()
{
     printf ("Hello World");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: please use parenthesis. `*p++` is ambiguous for a reader who can interpret it either as `*(p++)` or `(*p)++`

Comment: @UmNyobe:  If the reader cannot figure out which meaning is expressed, they should be looking at the rules of precedence not asking authors to coddle them with unnecessary parenthesis.  `*p++ = x;` is a common and historic idiom covered early in every C tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would very much prefer to do this:

```
char *p = new char[13];
char *q = p; 
*p=0x48;
++p;
*p=0x65;
++p;
*p=0x6c;
++p;
*p=0x6c;
++p;
*p=0x6f;
++p;
*p=0x20;
++p;
*p=0x57;
++p;
*p=0x6f;
++p;
*p=0x72;
++p;
*p=0x6c;
++p;
*p=0x64;
++p;
*p=0x0;
++p;

printf(q);
```

But the essence is that since it moves `--p` is needed to "reverse back up to the beginning", as a counter for the ++p that has been done to set the string.

[And without running it, I can see it prints `Hello World`]